# azure terraform What is the difference between subnet = var.XXXXXXX versus subnet_id = "{${var.XXXXXXX}""

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Unclear on the difference between a parameter (ie subnet_id) such as the following:  subnet_id = var.XXXXXXXXX , resource_group_name = "${ resource_created.XXXXXXXX.name}, subnet_id = "{$var.XXXXXXXXX}" , subnet_id = "{ "${azurerm_subnet.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.id}"?   When is ".id" required at the end of a parable output?  For example resource group creation has ".name" while IP configuration (IP_configuration)' subnet_id has a ".id" at the end ${azurerm_subnet.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.id} .

Is there a single link for all the possible formats such as .name, .location, .id,...?

browsed everywhere?   Sorry for the basic question but I am very new to azure terraform.

Answer (score 0):

you can look up all the resource reference and outputs using the api reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html

Comment: Previously looked at the link.  this is why I posted here.  The explanation was unsatisfactory.

Comment: well, nothing else would help you. that is the api reference.

Comment: Sorry but I am unfamiliar with how knowing if it is a API reference makes a difference ?   I am just wanting to know what can a parameter's value can be?

Comment: how knowing if it is a API reference makes a difference ?   I am just wanting to know what can a parameter's value can be?  Location = East US or Location = "{var.XXXXXXX}"  or subnet.id = "azurerm_create_test_resource.mything.id}".   Some parameters such as resource group creation have a .name , other have others like .id,...

Comment: because it describes what outputs do resources provide and you can figure out what you can use to pass into different other resources

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty dated question but since there is no satisfactory answer to a commonly asked question, it might be helpful for someone stumbling across this question.

The difference is in both usage as well as in style.

The interpolation syntax with the $ is old style and the usage with the var keyword the new style syntax. Using the old style may throw a warning and rather than changing the syntax manually, `tf fmt` can also resolve the style differences.